# I don't get what's the difference between format() and ... (python)

Tags: python, string, variables, python-3.x

Confused newbie here. What's the difference between using:

```
print ("So you are {0} years old".format(age))
```

AND

```
print ("So you are", age, "years old")
```

Both work.

Comment: Look closely...they aren't actually the same.

Comment: String formatting can be used in more contexts than just `print`.

Comment: In the latter case, the `print()` function is doing the work, so that syntax won't work anywhere except inside the `print()` function.  In the former case, the string instance method is doing the work, so that will work anywhere you have a string.

Comment: Remove the `print` and look what makes more sense.

Comment: related: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/4279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there's a huge difference. The former use string's [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.format) method to create a string. The latter, pass several arguments to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?#print) function, which will concatenate them all adding a whitespace (default) between them.

The former is far more powerful, for instance, you can use [the format syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to accomplish things like:

```
# trunc a float to two decimal places
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(3.4567)
'3.46'

# access an objects method
>>> import math
>>> '{.pi}'.format(math)
'3.141592653589793'
```

It is similar to `printf` style formats used in earlier versions of python with the `%` operator: (ie: `"%d" % 3`) Now `str.format()` is recommended over the `%` operator and is the new standard in Python 3.

Comment: [`%` operator is not deprecated though `str.format()` is recommended instead](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) e.g., `logging` modules uses `%` formatting.

Comment: You're right, I thought I read that somewhere in the docs but evidences hint the contrary. Thanks for correcting, I'll edit the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> class Age:
...     def __format__(self, format_spec):
...         return "{:{}}".format("format", format_spec)
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "str"
... 
>>> age = Age()
>>> print(age)
str
>>> print("{:s}".format(age))
format
```

`format()` allows to convert the same object into a string using different representations specified by `format_spec`. `print` uses `__str__` or `__repr__` if the former is not defined. `format()` may also use `__str__`, `__repr__` if `__format__` is not defined.

In Python 2 you could also define `__unicode__` method:

```
>>> class U:
...   def __unicode__(self):
...       return u"unicode"
...   def __str__(self):
...       return "str"
...   def __repr__(self):
...       return "repr"
... 
>>> u = U()
>>> print(u"%s" % u)
unicode
>>> print(u)
str
>>> print(repr(u))
repr
>>> u
repr
```

There is also `ascii()` builtin function in Python 3 that behaves like `repr()` but produces ascii-only results:

```
>>> print(ascii(""))
'\U0001f40d'
```

See [U+1F40D SNAKE](http://codepoints.net/U+1F40D).

`format()` uses [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) instead of running various conversion to string functions.

An object may invent its own `format_spec` language e.g., `datetime` allows to use `strftime` formats:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> "{:%c}".format(datetime.utcnow())
'Sun May  4 18:51:18 2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

The former is more convenient. Imagine if you have lots of parameters, you'll end up with something like this:

```
print ("So your name is ", firstname, " ", lastname, " and you are ", age, " years old")
```

This is a pain to both read and write. So the format method is there to help you write cleaner and more readable strings.

Comment: Those extra blanks aren't necessary; `print()` already inserts them.